# Problem to correct output a job list including the assigned category

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am using TYPO3 8.7
I would like to output a list of the current job offers including the corresponding category in my extention.

Here my code:

```
/**
 * Return all active jobs and join category title to each job
 *
 * @return QueryResult
 * @return array
 */
public function findAll()
{
/** @var QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_ats_domain_model_job');
    $statement = $queryBuilder
      ->select('tx_ats_domain_model_job.uid', 'tx_ats_domain_model_job.title', 'tx_ats_domain_model_job.job_number')
      ->from('tx_ats_domain_model_job')
      ->addSelect('tx_ats_domain_model_category.title')
      ->from('tx_ats_domain_model_category')
      ->join(
            'tx_ats_domain_model_job',
            'tx_ats_domain_model_category',
            'categories',
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('categories.uid', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('tx_ats_domain_model_job.cat'))
      )->execute();
      $results = $statement->fetch();
      return $results;
}
```

When I do the following:

```
->select('tx_ats_domain_model_job.uid')
->from('tx_ats_domain_model_job')
```

All actual jobs are listed - but no content.

When I do the following:

```
->select('tx_ats_domain_model_job.uid', 'tx_ats_domain_model_job.title', 'tx_ats_domain_model_job.job_number')
->from('tx_ats_domain_model_job')
```

All actual jobs are listed width the job title (no job number) – but each job three times, once per select statement.

When I do the following:

```
->select('tx_ats_domain_model_job.uid', 'tx_ats_domain_model_job.title', 'tx_ats_domain_model_job.job_number')
->from('tx_ats_domain_model_job')
->addSelect('tx_ats_domain_model_category.title')
->from('tx_ats_domain_model_category')
```

Its going even worse. All categories assigned to a current job are listed. But again the same: by six categories all are listed six times each.

Can someone give a hint where my mistake lies? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If in tx_ats_domain_model_job.cat stands only the uid from tx_ats_domain_model_category then it must be

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_ats_domain_model_job');
    $statement = $queryBuilder
        ->select('tx_ats_domain_model_job.uid', 'tx_ats_domain_model_job.title', 'tx_ats_domain_model_job.job_number', 'tx_ats_domain_model_category.title')
        ->from('tx_ats_domain_model_job')
        ->leftJoin(
            'tx_ats_domain_model_job',
            'tx_ats_domain_model_category',
            'categories',
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('categories.uid', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('tx_ats_domain_model_job.cat'))
        )->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetch();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your assumption is correct, in tx_ats_domain_model_job.cat is the uid of tx_ats_domain_model_category.
Your solution leads me to the error message

Unknown column 'tx_ats_domain_model_category.catname' in 'field list'.

I only configured tx_ats_domain_model_category.title in the Domain Model category. Do I have to plan something?

Greetings from Switzerland

Comment: Hm, do you have in ext_tables.sql or in Configuration/TCA/tx_ats_domain_model_category.php in the TCA a defintion of the field catname, that not exits in the database table? Because the querybuilder does not access this field? My query access only the fields uid and title in the table tx_ats_domain_model_category...

Comment: uh ..., sorry, my mistake. I renamed the field in the database from "title" to "catname" – don't ask why.
In TCA "catname" is defined as a field type input
and in Domain Model as * @var string */protected with the corresponding get and set
kind regards